# PHP Downloaded File does not match Server File size

Tags: php

I use a simple code in PHP to download a file and calculates its MD5 to verify the download was completed as expected, but I have noticed that PHP even when it is downloading a healthy, complete file, it is slightly bigger than the one in the server for few bytes, hence causing the MD5 check to fail.

This is the PHP code I'm using:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($_GET['a']);
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
$file_path  = 'temp/' . $file_name;

if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    $size = filesize($file_path);

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($file_path);
}    
else
    echo 'File does not exists';
?>
```

In the server I have a .ZIP file which weights 203 bytes, but the downloaded file is 254 bytes or higher. So, what am I doing wrong that can't make the PHP to download a complete simple file?

To download the file I use `C# WebClient` or Goolgle-Chrome and I get the same result in both.

Comment: Does the zip contain the correct data?

Comment: Probably something to do with the server being unix and the receiveing system being windows

Comment: Have you tried with other headers? I'd suggest to remove "Content-Transfer-Encoding" .. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62074

Comment: @Kaii Yes, I have tried other headers, but the file is still a bit higher in size. The downloaded file is correct, in the sense that it opens and it works, but cannot check the MD5 because of this detail.

Comment: Did you already look at that file? If I've had to make an educated guess, I'd assume this is a minimalistic excerpt from the code you are using. If so, I'd guess there is output (like. echo $html_head or something) happening before or after this excerpt of code. I mean: Open the ZIP in a text editor to check for leading or trailing output.

Comment: @Kaii Something is being added to the file, but I have no idea what is it.

Comment: Can you find out if it's a block of content added at the beginning or at the end?